# Android: pass on a "Clicked" status?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using a Linear Layout inside of a dialog, and have some TextViews inside that layout that I would also like to change color based on the "pressed" state of the Layout that is their parent. They have a state-list for what color they should be, but it seems that when the layout is clicked, the Views beneath it are not given that "clicked" state.

How could I make the TextViews change color when their parent layout is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is just to pass the event down into whatever the child views are.  You can extend TextView and add a method that you can call from the Layout's onclick handler.

```
class MyTV extends TextView{

  public MyTV(Context c){
    //constructor gets context in case you want to make instances from code rather than XML
  }
  public doSomethingToMe(){
     //do stuff to this View from outside
  }
}
```

then in your Activity...

```
public void layoutClicked(View v){ //call this from your layout click
   ((MyTV)findViewById(R.id.myTV1)).doSomethingToMe();
}
```

Comment: How can I tell when the press event is done so I can change the color back?

Comment: Like so: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html Rather than listening for onClick, listen for onTouch and react to both the DOWN and UP events. You won't be able to do this through XML, you'll need to create the listener in code and attach it to your Layout.